# Select a radio control from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have a group of 2 asp radio controls and I want to choose one of them on ajax postback. I can put breakpoints and can tell the code is being hit, but nothing is happening. I have tried good 5-10 different variations, but nothing seems to work. The .css bit was to test that I can find the right control and that is working. The CSS gets applied.

I have tried `.trigger("click")` , also `attr(checked="checked" and true)`. Have tried anything that I could find on Google. But the second option is not getting checked.

```
 $("[main=true]").Checked = true;
 $("[main=true]").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

Html

```
<asp:RadioButton GroupName="Complete" runat="server" Text="Yes" Checked="true" />
<asp:RadioButton GroupName="Complete" runat="server" Text="No" main="true" /><br />
```

Another minor issue I seem to be having is that if I click on the words "Yes" or "No" both option boxes get un-selected. Any reason for that?

```
        $(window).load(function () {
        $("[main=false]").prop('checked', false);
        $("[main=true]").prop('checked', true);
        $("[main=true]").prop('checked', true);
        $("[main=true]").attr('checked', true);
        $("[main=true]").Checked = true;
        $("[main=true]").css("background-color", "yellow");
        var id = localStorage.getItem("CustomerID");
        $('img[alt = "' + id + '"]').trigger("click");
        localStorage.clear();
    });
```

The HTML out put

```
 <span>Mark as complete:</span><span main="false">
 <input id="gvCustomers_ctl07_0" type="radio" name="gvCustomers$ctl02   $Complete" value="ctl07" checked="checked" />
   <label for="gvCustomers_ctl07_0">Yes</label>
  </span><span main="true"><input id="gvCustomers_ctl08_0" type="radio"     name="gvCustomers$ctl02$Complete" value="ctl08" />
      <label for="gvCustomers_ctl08_0">No</label></span>
```

By the way there are more than one radio controls with main attribute  set to true, but I want all of them to get selected. Not sure if that makes any difference. What doesn't make sense is that the CSS is getting applied.

Comment: `$("[main=true]").Checked = true;` should be `$("[main=true]").prop('checked', true);`

Comment: Tried that too, doesn't work.

Comment: So your issue comes from somewhere else. We don't know how you are trying to call this code. And how is rendered `<asp:RadioButton GroupName="Complete" runat="server" Text="No" main="true" />` client side?

Comment: The JS is triggered on page load. I have added the full function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577238/dynamically-get-radio-button-group-name-using-jquery

Comment: Try this `$("[main=true]").attr('checked', true).trigger('change');`

Comment: Change your selectors `$("[main=false] input[type=radio]").prop('checked', false);` and `$("[main=true] input[type=radio]").prop('checked', true);` Here is a [**JsFiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/rd8dxevv/)

Comment: Thanks newToJS, still nothing.

Comment: @SANM2009 check you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: Use `.attr("checked", "checked")` instead of `.attr(checked="checked")`. And try to reset another radio button before do it.

Comment: What is *main* attribute? I didn't see one in specification..

Comment: It is a custom attribute I have used to identify the controls. Because the name and id get changed on page load (the controls are in gridview template item)

Answer (score 0):

I have a confusion, How can HTML be

```
<asp:RadioButton GroupName="Complete" runat="server" Text="Yes" Checked="true" />
```

According to my knowledge, No matter what programing language you use, it is first converted to HTML and then rendered in the browser.

So as much i can assume, you code will be getting converted to

```
<input name='Complete' type='radio'  checked='true'></input>
<input name='Complete' type='radio' main='true'></input>
```

A very simple & naive solution to your problem will be

```
var elemArray=document.getElementsByName("Complete");
elemArray[0].checked=true;//For 1 radio
elemArray[1].checked=true; //For 2 radio
```

or you can simply iterate over the element array

```
for(i=0;i<elem.length;i++){
if(elem[i].hasAttribute('main')){
elem[i].checked=true;//if the second element do not have any main attribute
//or
if(elem[i].main='true'){
elem[i].checked=true;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry I am a bit old school. What I mean is the asp file, not the code behind.

Comment: Don't think it would work, the controls are dynamically duplicated, hence I am using custom attribute "main" to find them.

Comment: Doesn't make any difference if the elements are dynamically generated or already there if the element is there when you will be running the function to select one of them, and I have provided a solution with the main attribute also.

Comment: I think you should also provide the generated HTML code, that would surely help everyone else to eliminate error

Comment: Jatin, The HTMl is attached. Thanks for the comment, I think I see the issue. The main attribute is becoming a span outside of the input control. Which would explain why css is being applied. I think I need .(next) in my code.

Comment: Jatin, The HTML output is attached above. Thanks for the comment, I think I see the issue. The main attribute is becoming a span outside of the input control. Which would explain why css is being applied. I think I need .next() in my code.

Comment: yes, but to me it doesn't seem very great option, because creation of <span > is uncertain or not known, what you can do is to include the radio buttons in a div and then use child selector on that div, Or maybe if possible, make name of the radio buttons fixed, if there is some change need to be done  dynamically use id attribute for that.